# Report for Product view count and total quantity ordered

Tags: reports, magento-1.5.1

I want to have custom report which will show Product view count and total quantity ordered and ratio of these two in a report.

Please give me some idea how I can create this report in admin.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can start from the table `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily` and join it with the `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`.  Both contain product_id and names.

I can also take care about products with zero views/purchases, probably as a separate section.

Comment: Thanks, Also can you please guide me towards any good tutorial for creating new custom reports.

Comment: You can just create a new extension with a menu item and grid, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704729/magento-custom-module-with-custom-database-table-admin-page for example